# XSLT / XPATH Attribute Selection using another attribute as a predicate

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I'd like to select the value of a certain attribute from all tags where another attribute matches a condition.

For example, if my XML document is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<doc>
  <mytag txt="alpha" foo="a"></mytag>
  <mytag txt="beta"  foo="b"></mytag>
</doc>
```

I'd like to use a XSLT file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="doc/mytag">
      |<xsl:value-of select="@txt[@foo='a']"/>|
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

To get output like this:

```
|alpha|
```

Instead, nothing is selected.

If I wrap the [xsl:value-of] tag with a [xsl:if test="@foo='a'"] tag, it will work:

```
...
<xsl:for-each select="doc/mytag">
  <xsl:if test="@foo='a'">
    |<xsl:value-of select="@txt"/>|
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

But I'd like to avoid that if possible, simply to save on space since I have ~20 separate tags I'd like to extract.

I'm guessing this is an xpath problem, but after fairly lengthy searching, I haven't found a solution. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Change `@txt[@foo='a']` to `[@foo='a']/@txt`

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't work - no output at all, not even the bar (|) characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax you are looking for is this....

```
|<xsl:value-of select="@txt[../@foo='a']"/>|
```

However, this would outout `||` in the case where `@foo` wasn't equal to `a`. So, what you could do is more the condition to the `xsl:for-each` instead

```
<xsl:for-each select="doc/mytag[@foo='a']">
  |<xsl:value-of select="@txt"/>|
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Thanks, the first syntax worked great.The second syntax won't work in my particular case, because there's one instance of each variable (eg @foo='a', @foo='b') for each node, so I'd have to have one for-each for each variable.

Comment: @OoO You don't need multiple `for-each` elements. Add a condition for each `foo` attribute value to the predicate separated by an `or` operator. Or if the tree varies more significantly per selection, you can use independent XPath expressions separated by an `|` operator.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this would be better done using a template:

```
<transform xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <output method="text"/>
    <template match="child::doc/child::mytag[count(attribute::foo) = 1 and (string(attribute::foo) = 'a' or string(attribute::foo) = 'c')]">
        <value-of select="concat('|', string(attribute::txt), '|')"/>
    </template>
</transform>
```